# Is solana.stackexchange.com just about programming with Solana?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-scope

Are topics like 'how are the minimum requirements for validators calculated?' or 'how does Solana compare to (some other Layer 1)' appropriate?

Comment: Not sure if it's worth a separate question so I'm just adding a comment here as it seems related, what about questions about open source contributions? E.g people looking for clarification on how to proceed when they get stuck.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we want SE community to be exclusively about **programming** on Solana. It's not `solana-programming.stackexchange.com`.

There are many potential questions about

- how Solana works in general,
- how validators work,
- possible error when running the CLI,
- issues when using Solana or Solana apps as an end user,

that I would expect this community to be about. As long as questions meet other criteria, of course.

Answer (score 3):

`how does Solana compare to (some other Layer 1)' appropriate` likely is not a good questions because it requires a very opinionated answer most of the time. You could ask something more direct that requires a fact as an answer

`how are the minimum requirements for validators calculated?` This is probably ok.

Any questions about core architecture, developing on Solana, and validator/RPC setup should be fine imo

Comment: It is possible to do a non opinionated comparison of Layer 1s. The point of the meta question is that how they differ is a non programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it focused *exclusively* on Solana "programming"?

In an *inclusive* to peripheral Solana focused things kind of a way, sure!

Either of those topic examples seem like perfectly fair territory, especially in a beta phase of a community's development :)

Jacob Creech makes a good point about question soundness.  A focused comparative analytical question is one thing, but when unfocused such inquiry invites speculation.

At this stage, I think a slightly wider net is alright.

Comment: This answer is vague - I don't think 'focused exclusively on Solana programming in an inclusive to peripheral Solana focused things kind of a way' is logically possible. We either exclude or include. I think you mean we say we want to include non-programming topics but it's not clear.